# Regex removing extra characters

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I'm using this pattern `[^a-z0-9+\ ,#\-.]` to filter tags before saving them to my database.

It works with an undesired side-effect; it removes accents: `instalação` becomes `instalao`

Any idea how I can keep accents intact while sticking to the pattern?

I'm using ColdFusion, so I assume it's based on Java Regex, but I could be wrong.

My intention is to allow letters (with accents), 0 to 9 arabic numbers, dots and hashes.

Comment: You sure about ColdFusion having a regex implementation based on Java?

Comment: @Bart, not positive, but I imagine so. It's got tight integration with Java, and you can call java methods directly. CF/Railo engines run on JRun/Tomcat respectively...

Comment: no, I just checked the [ColdFusion documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a38f-7ffb.html): it's not like Java... at all! :)

Comment: @BartKiers, interesting! I had no idea! I'll test your answer against Donut's--although his initial one `\w` seems to work!

Comment: Yeah, `\w` might work for you, but it matches any digit (not just `0-9`) _and_ it matches underscores.

Comment: Whilst CF's built-in regex is Apache ORO, it is possible to access java.util.regex from CF, (and I've got a project where I've wrapped the Java stuff inside convenient a cfc and custom tag if anyone is interested).

Comment: @Peter, do you have it up on GitHub? I'd love to have a look!

Comment: Not on GitHub just yet, but you can download it from [cfregex.net](http://cfregex.net/) (which also has info & docs about it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According [the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0a38f-7ffb.html) `\w` matches any (Unicode) letter, digit but also underscores. If you don't want underscores, the you can do this:

```
[^[:alpha:]0-9#.-]
```

where `[:alpha:]` matches any (Unicode) letter. If you want to match digits outside the `0-9` range, try:

```
[^[:alnum:]##.-]
```

Note, the extra hash to escape ColdFusion's own tags, otherwise it would result in a mal-formed tag/variable error.

Comment: Removed my answer so as not to cause confusion.

Comment: @Donut, you were thrown off-base a bit by the remark that it was Java-style regex...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the character classes? **\w** matches letters, numbers and underscore, and may just match accented characters, although I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
[^\w]
```

\w matches any word character. In this case all non-word characters.
or

```
\W
```

to match all non-word characters.

Comment: There is no need to put brackets around `\W`.